# What do these numbers in a 'hexdump' of a file mean?

Tags: files, hexdump

I created a simple file, *1.txt*:

```
echo "hello" >> 1.txt
```

Then I dumped it:

```
hexdump 1.txt
```

And the terminal output:

```
0000000 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                              
0000006
```

What do `0000000` and  `0000006` mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*0000000* in this example is the offset (hexadecimal, counted from the start of the file) of the first byte printed in a particular line.

*0000006* in this example is the number (in hexadecimal) of bytes in a file. There are five characters in the word "hello" and a line feed character (0x0A).

Try echoing a longer text or repeating `echo "hello" >> 1.txt` several times to increase the size of the file. Then see the `hexdump` results.

Comment: What if I add bits after `0000006` ? do the file raise error ? can I put secret bits there ?

Comment: `000006` isn't part of the file. It's just a number indicating how big the file is. You can't put bits "after" it, because it's not there. You can add bits to the end of the file, but all that will do is make the file larger.

Comment: Actually, you can probably put a few bits there, because file allocation is almost always done in blocks. That is to say, your 6 byte file might occupy the first 6 bytes of a 4096 byte block, and then the remaining 4090 bytes will **not be used by another file**. You would need raw disk access to access these "secret" bits.

Comment: @TheSpooniest Thanks. I'd be glad to add bits after the file, nevermind it is larger, if these added bits are not visible in te file content.

Comment: There's no way to add data to a file that isn't visible in the file contents and doesn't contribute to the length. The 00000 / 00006 are just bits of information printed by the `od` program. (@MSalters technique is hiding bits on the disk, which won't be shown in `od`)

Comment: @AMind you: Those bits will in fact be so secret that `cp` won't know them, and won't copy them.

Comment: With this talk about adding bits/data, how exactly is it being proposed to add these?

Comment: Please just post [new questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you have them. The discussion about writing data to the raw disk in unused parts of the block has nothing to do with the question, and seems to be confusing people